# Are misplaced, unused anchor bolts a problem?

Tags: framing

In the garage wall at the front porch there are two anchor bolts not installed in the wall. You can actually see the anchor bolts.

The whole wall is 3 degrees off from concrete slab, I guess it was measured incorrectly. 1/4 of the wall is barely standing on the concrete.

This is brand new house we built just finished inspection yesterday.
How do we know the builder will fix it right way? Will this be a serious issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many bolts in total are exposed? How many walls?

Answer (score 2):

Sloppy workmanship aside (could have been the mason or the carpenters), this probably isn't a serious issue. Anchor bolts are most critical in tornado and earthquake zones, but there are usually many installed, and a few that miss won't substantially increase the chance of disaster.

The builder should at least cut them off neatly, flush with the concrete. They're ugly and a bit of a safety concern. If they won't do that, you can do so with a metal-cutting blade in a reciprocating saw or hack saw.

As a resolution I'd ask whether new bolts were drilled into the foundation when it was discovered that the wall would miss the original bolts. If not, you'll have to decide whether to pursue the matter in a legal sense.

Comment: That's my concern as well.  Did the builder add new anchor bolts.  Granted these are only needed in so-called "worst-case" scenarios but the number of bolts should be defined by your building code and they are the way they are for a reason.  Namely structural engineers have determined that a certain number of anchor bolts are needed in whatever scenario they have determined to design to.

Comment: Sure, but the fact of the matter is that almost any project has a couple that miss, or fall in doorways, or whatever. There's overhead built into bolt schedules for such situations. You're right, but it comes down to total number and location.

Comment: I have a lot of trouble assuming that everything is OK when I see such sloppy workmanship.  On top of that, it's mostly covered up now and so you don't know what else is lurking behind that drywall.